# Select Objects from List where they meet a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following javascript object containing three objects:

```
var list = [
    { age: 5  },
    { age: 10 },
    { age: 15 }
];
```

Is there a way of selecting a subset of elements based on age using JavaScript and JQuery? For example:

`$.select(list, element.age>=10);`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is there a way of selecting a subset of elements based on age…

Yes.

> …using JavaScript…

[Array `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
list.filter(function(element){ return element.age >= 10; })
```

> …and jQuery

[`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
$.grep(list, function(element){ return element.age >= 10; })
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, that's not JSON, it's an array literal filled with object literals.

[`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep) is handy here:

```
var filtered = $.grep(list, function (el) {
    return el.age >= 10;
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ytmhR/

Comment: To clarify, technically an array is a valid json.